# "Golden" implementation for MVVM Light

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mvvm, uwp, mvvm-light

The question can be summarized in: Which is the best way to develop a clear app on UWP with MVVM Light? Maybe I missed it but I’ve not found a sample or similar…

I’ve seen a lot of discussion and variation: 
Model – do I put only data here or I should create e DAL model? If I use EF do I need 2 layers (DAL and Model)?

Should it be observable? The load/save or populate methods should be here or in a DAL?

Then we move to an upper level: If you have a list in a class (example company – employee) the List object is in the Model or in the ViewModel?

But if I have the Model Company and a list of companies (List) gathered via a LINQ on EF how do I transform that into a `ObservableCollection<CompanyViewModel>`? should I have to do a loop and add new objects? is not very efficient and nice... isn't there a better way?

Do Models raise ContentChanged? (it appears to me the answer to be no, it should be raised by the view model)

For the ViewModel do you map the view models based on the views (so main form ViewModel, TreeView ViewModel) or on the data (`CompanyViewModel`)? or both (in this case why?)?

All ViewModels should be Observable so all actions should raise content changed here or below?

I've seen all possible answers so this is why I'm asking:; which is the "golden" way? the "best practice"?
I know almost all of them "could work" but my objective is to know the "best" (= more efficient, clean from a design perspective, etc...).

Comment: The DAL is part of the model in MVVM. You may inject a view model with a reference to the DAL or a service that uses the DAL to fecth the data from the database. Then it's the responsibility of the view model or a client side service, to "transform" the data. Wwhat's "not very efficient" with a plain old loop?

Answer (score 0):

In the case of propagating changes in the data source to the UI, your suggested solution of looping through and adding the new objects is not as bad as it sounds. If your data source contains a "last changed" property that would allow you to filter only the actual changes, you could get only the changed data. Otherwise, you have to query the full number of items anyway, so doing another loop over the data does not change the complexity (still linear with the number of items). If you have some kind of IDs, you can then just check if such id is present in the `ObservableCollection` and add it then.

For your second question, from my experience, the way you structure and partition your view models is rather a thing of personal preference and may be different from case to case. I usually have a **view model for the page** and then also create **view models to wrap data models** (for example for list items, etc.). However, in case the view model grows more complex, I usually partition it and create **view models responsible for specific areas of the UI**. These are then accessible as properties of the view model for the page itself - this way you get proper separation of concerns.